# SVG special Characters like <sup>2</sup> or &$178; or &sup2;

Tags: unicode, svg, special-characters, highcharts

I am trying to put on SVG the special character ( <sup>2</sup> ) ( --> &#178; ) with no result. Is there a way to put unicode characters on SVG ?

Here is an example code using highcharts 2.1.6

```
<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>​

$(function() {
    var renderer = new Highcharts.Renderer(
    $('#container')[0],
    400,
    300);
    renderer.text(100, 100, 100, 100, 5).attr({
        'stroke-width': 2,
        zIndex: 3,
        rotation: 170,
        text: 'sdfsdf&#178;'
    }).add();
});​
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Exactly what did you try? A pure SVG file, or SVG embedded in something else, like HTML. Please post code and specify the software on which you viewed the data, and what does “no result” mean (nothing displayed)? The character “²” as such works in SVG, when the character encoding is properly set and specified, and the character reference `&#178;` works independently of character encoding. (But it must have `#`, not `$` as in the question heading.)

Comment: Also, the font used must have support for that codepoint.